# Exclamation mark in Typescript but not non-nullable type assertion

Tags: angular, typescript

Found some interesting code in Angular 5.2 typescript sources:

1. Exclamation mark in front of array index variable [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-webworker/src/web_workers/shared/service_message_broker.ts#L64)

   `signature ![i]`
2. Exclamation mark in front of function call parentheses [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-webworker/src/web_workers/shared/service_message_broker.ts#L76)

   `this._methods.get(message.method) !(message);`

Tried this syntax in Typescript playground - no errors: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20signature%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B'test'%5D%0D%0Alet%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(signature%20!%5Bi%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20true%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Af%20!()%3B%0D%0A)

But still cannot find/understand what does it mean. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I try to answer it.

The empty space around ! is not important. The ! in your case is also unnecessary. But if modify it a little bit, you see the problem:

```js
let signature: Array<any>|undefined = ['test']
let i = 0;
console.log(signature ! [i])
signature=undefined
console.log(signature ! [i]) // <= crash
```

With ! you say: *object before is not null*. Typescript trust you and if your assumption is wrong, compiled Javascript will fail.